Why are non Hindus not allowed inside Puri Jagannatha Temple?
So I recently came to know that Pathitha Pavana Jagannatha Murti near the temple and it is for the people in rajaswala dhosham and non Hindus so they can have dharshanam of him. Is there any other specific reasons or referenced behind this story?

The Bhagavatam states that Brahma made Indra free from the sin of brahmahatya (incurred from the slaying of Vishwarupa) by dividing it among land (borne in the form of deserts), trees (borne in the form of sap), water (borne in the form of foam) & women (borne in the form of menstrual blood). Hence women in their menses are considered impure. And speaking of others, non-Hindus were prohibited from entering any Hindu temple. Scriptural mandate lumped non-Hindus on par with untouchables. But after denying temple entry to antyajas was made illegal, Hindus had to accept entry of non-Hindus too.

@অনু Do you know when was Pathitha Pavana Jagannatha Murthi installed in the temple? I heard a story of a king converting to another faith and for his sake Jagannatha asked the priests to make a idol of his face and install him there. Is this folklore or has any basis?

The Patitapavana icon is situated at the doorway of the main temple. And the story of its manifestation has also been heard. And there is no reason for that anecdote to be false.

As per āgamas, it's niṣiddha for aspṛśyas to enter in mandiras of Viṣṇu and Śiva, these include rajasvalā strī, antyajas (such as cāṇḍālas, etc.), pātakīs, mlecchas, etc. Those who are non-Hindus are generally aśraddhālu, they wouldn't follow any rules of śaucam, etc., so not allowing them entry is a reasonable restriction. Restriction on the entry of non-Hindus (such as Kirishitans or Mausulas) and aspṛśyas should be the case in all pratiṣṭhita mandiras.

But it must be noted that although aspṛśya, etc. are varjita from mandirapraveśa, still darśana of just mandiradvāra or gopuram for them, is equivalent to darśana of devatā in mandira. They would gain the same phala. So, it's not a matter to lament about. There is a certain vidhāna which is meant to be followed. If you don't have śraddhā in vidhāna, you don't have śraddhā in the mandira and its deva.
